# Want to Featch data from JSON file. And got data in tabuler form. But know I want to search data by alphabelicaly order A-Z / Z-A formate

Tags: javascript, json, html

Data fetched from JSON file and got data in tabular form. But know I want to search data in order to A-Z / Z-A format.
want to search data by ordered A-Z / Z-A format.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you add more details?

Comment: <script src="dump-data.js"></script>
<script>
    String.prototype.toRealValue = function () {
        return (isNaN(this)) ? this.toLowerCase() : parseInt(this);
    }
    var getData = users;
    var tbodyElem = document.getElementById("tbody");
    function showdata()    {
       for (let x in users)       {
            tbodyElem.innerHTML +=
                 `<tr><td>${users[x].id}</td>
                      <td>${users[x].employee_name}</td>
                      <td>${users[x].employee_salary}</td>
                      <td>${users[x].employee_age}</td></tr>`;
       }    }

Comment: using above code got the data in tabular form from JSON file.

Comment: function searchTxt(search) {
             getData = [];
        if(search.length > 1) {
                for (let x in search) {
                    console.log(search); 
                    tbodyElem.innerHTML +=
                        `<tr><td>${search[x].id}</td>
                      <td>${search[x].employee_name}</td>
                      <td>${search[x].employee_salary}</td>
                      <td>${search[x].employee_age}</td>      </tr>`;
                }
            }
         //else { getData = users;
        //}
        showdata(getData);    }

Comment: With searchTxt need to search data in order a-z / z-a. nd output will show in same tabuler form only. Got the search data in console.log(). But not display in tabular form.

Comment: @Samuel -- I have updated my code in above comments.